# A "between" relationship between three nodes in neo4j or a graph db

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am struggling to visualize a "between" relationship between three nodes in a graph db (neo4j, for example).

Say, I want to establish the fact that `B` is between `A` and `C`. I don't have any positional property for the nodes (say, lat/long) which I could use to do a 'between' evaluation. I just have purely the fact that B is between A and C.

In other words, to give an example, the middle finger is between the index finger and the ring finger. Say if I don't know the position or order (which I could have defined as one property of each finger and used it), but just the fact that middle finger is between the other two fingers. How can I store this fact in a graph db or neo4j.

To add complexity, it's also possible that B is between D and E. I need to figure out how to answer questions like what B is between (Answer A,C and D,E) or what is between A and C (Answer: B).

How can this be logically achieved in a graph DB / Neo4j?

Here is an image for illustration: [image]

Comment: Where did you read about this "between" relationship?  I can't find a reference to it anywhere.  Normally a relationship is associated with two nodes, not three.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question.  Did you really mean to capitalize and quote the word 'between'?  The fact that you did makes me think it's a keyword of some sort.

Comment: If it's not a keyword, and you're just asking how to tell whether a given node is between two other nodes, I think you need to define what you mean by between.  Does it mean Nodes A,B, and C have to be on a straight line with B in the middle?  Or does it just mean B has to have a direct connection to both A and C, but A and C do not have a direct connection?

Comment: Sorry if capitalizing confused you. I didn't mean it was a keyword. By between, I mean physically. As in, the middle finger is between the index finger and the ring finger. Only, in my case, I don't know the position or order (which I could have defined as one property of each finger and used it).

Comment: I still don't think you've sufficiently defined 'between'.  Fingers have different constraints than nodes do.  Do the three nodes have to be on a straight line in order for the middle node to be considered between the two others?  If you have a triangle with nodes A,B,C at the corners of the triangle, is each node 'between' the other two nodes, or not?

Comment: Okay - so since I am very new to this, I may have used the word "node" in wrong manner.

What I mean by node is any entity / object. In my example, I am using fingers as nodes. (In neo4j, I think this would mean Label, I think).

And no, the triangle example doesn't fit my problem description.

Comment: If fingers are nodes.... what are the edges (connections)?  What relationships exist between each of your fingers?  Is there a direct  connection from each finger to each other finger, or do the direct connections only exist between adjacent fingers?  My point with all these questions is I still don't understand your definition of 'between', and I don't think the finger analogy is helpful at all.   I can't see your image though; maybe that clarifies things.  Can you explain WHY B is not between A and C on triangle ABC?  Is it because they don't lie on a straight line?

Comment: @pabrams, The relationship between fingers is only their position relative to each other. My broader goal is to map basic human anatomy to a graph. Fingers are attached to Palm which is part of the Hand which is attached to a Shoulder and so on. My question is a specific subset of larger problem. I hope this answers your question. **I am not interested in triangle as that's not the question I am trying to solve here**. Unless you are telling me that I can't use Graph database to describe human body.

Comment: You can use a graph to describe the human body, but based on your description, none of your fingers are directly attached to each other and so none are between any of the others (nor is your middle finger on the shortest path from your index to your ring finger) ; you say they are all attached to your palm. My triangle analogy is a simplification of your problem that was trying to help point this out. **You should be interested in a triangle because it's a very simple graph.** If you can't understand the triangle, you will have no hope of understanding how to map the human body into a graph.

Comment: I can see the image now that I'm at home.  You didn't draw any edges....?  So how is B between the other nodes?  It can only be based on positional data, right?  Also, which nodes correspond to which fingers?  I don't see how the answer given by Dave Bennett can give you what you want, because he's assumed a standard definition of between which is not the same as yours. Also the graph he's creating has edges that create paths essential to his concept of between, but your example has no edges so there is no path from any node to any other node.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you mean that the nodes are in a linear relationship created by something like this...

```
create (a:Test {name: 'A'})
create (b:Test {name: 'B'})
create (c:Test {name: 'C'})
create (a)-[:NEXT]->(b)
create (b)-[:NEXT]->(c)
return *
```

Then you could match a path and check for the existence of **B** in that path.

```
match p=(:Test {name: 'A'})-[:NEXT*2..]->(:Test {name: 'C'})
where 'B' in extract(node IN nodes(p) | node.name)
return p
```

If you wanted to find out what nodes **B** was between, then you can start with B and look for the adjacent nodes.  If you do not specify a vector in the relationships you will get the same set of nodes twice but in opposite order.  If you compare the adjacent nodes though in a where clause you can reduce the resulting list to distinct pairs.

```
match (left:Test )--(:Test {name: 'B'})--(right:Test) 
where left.name < right.name
return left, right
```

If we create a few more nodes (D and E) and wire them up to B you can get similar results.

```
match (b:Test {name: 'B'})
with b
create (d:Test {name: 'D'})-[:NEXT]->(b)
create (b)-[:NEXT]->(e:Test {name: 'E'})
```

But unless you name your relationships differently or add some other attribute(s) you will not be able to preserve the distinct tracks.

```
match (left:Test )-->(:Test {name: 'B'})-->(right:Test) 
return left, right
```

If we transform the data a little by creating specific relationships between the nodes then we can have more control over what we return.

```
// create the 'A_LINE'
match (a:Test {name: 'A'})-->(b:Test {name: 'B'})-->(c:Test {name: 'C'}) 
create (a)-[:A_LINE]->(b)-[:A_LINE]->(c)


// create the 'D_LINE'
match (d:Test {name: 'D'})-->(b:Test {name: 'B'})-->(e:Test {name: 'E'}) 
create (d)-[:D_LINE]->(b)-[:D_LINE]->(e)
```

For instance, now you can ask for items on a specific relationship type.

```
// return adjacent nodes on the 'A_LINE'
match (left:Test )-[:A_LINE]->(:Test {name: 'B'})-[:A_LINE]->(right:Test) 
return left, right

// return adjacent nodes on the 'D_LINE'
match (left:Test )-[:D_LINE]->(:Test {name: 'B'})-[:D_LINE]->(right:Test) 
return left, right
```

Or with a little extra effort you can ask for different lines simultaneously and sort them out into the appropriate combinations after the fact.

```
match p=(:Test )-[:A_LINE|D_LINE]->(:Test {name: 'B'})-[:A_LINE|D_LINE]->(:Test)
with p, relationships(p) as rels
unwind rels as r
with p, collect(distinct type(r)) as rels 
where size(rels) = 1
return head(rels), head(nodes(p)), last(nodes(p))
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tested this yet, but I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I just started on learning graph db/theory, and I just couldn't think of "next" relationship. I will accept this answer once I get to test it.

Comment: Looks like this will test whether B is in a path from A to C, which is a very specific (and to me not very intuitive) definition of 'between'.  If this indeed is the answer to your question, it might be good to edit the question to change the language so it's more clear and useful to future readers.

Comment: Dave, your solution worked if the question is "What lies between A and C". But how can I answer the question "What is B between".

Also, it's possible that B is between D and E. (See my edit in the original question). I think your approach still works if I add relations the same way for D->B->E, but I still can't answer the question of "What is B between" (Answer: A,C and D,E).

@pabrams: I have edited the original question.

Comment: A different version of this: `MATCH (b:Test {name:'B'})
MATCH p=(:Test {name:'A'})-[:NEXT*2..]->(:Test {name:'C'})
WHERE b IN nodes(p)
RETURN p` or even `IN nodes(p)[1..-1]`